# Java - method that add element then multiply every element in a list

Tags: java, list, methods, addition, alternate

can I please for a help in this exercise? I exhausted my knowledge, after many hours.
I need to write a static method in Java that takes as a parameter list of numbers and returns int value. The value is a result of adding and multiplying alternate numbers in a list. As a addition I CANNOT use the modulo % to take odd or even index from loop.
How can I break the J inner loop, it is not incrementing when I use break, so j index is always 2. I am complete beginner.

As a example: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] should be as a result: (1 + 2 * 3 + 4 * 5) = 27

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Exercise {
    static int addAndMultiply(List<Integer> list) {
        boolean flag = true;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if(flag) {
                    sum+= list.get(i) + list.get(j);
                    flag = false;

                }  else {
                    sum += list.get(i) * list.get(j);
                    flag = true;
                }
            } break;
        }
        return sum;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        Collections.addAll(numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        System.out.println(Exercise.addAndMultiply(numbers));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output for [1, 2, 3, 4] and [1,2] inputs?

Comment: Generalizing the query from @IamGroot - what is the expected behavior for lists that are even-sized?  `[1,2,3,4] = 1 + 2*3 + 4` ?  It isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve with the two loops here.  Are you familiar with using an Iterator (see List.iterator())?

Comment: Thank you for responce. The input is a list:  [1, 2, 3, 4], expected output is number from adding and multiplying alternate elements like this: [1 + 2 * 3 + 4 * 5 + 6 * 7 ...]. @vsfDawg Thank you I will make a research if this is resolve for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
static int addAndMultiply(List<Integer> list) {
    int result = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1 ; i < list.size() ; i = i+2) {
        if (i == list.size()-1) {
            result += list.get(i);
        } else {
            result += list.get(i) * list.get(i+1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is probably what the instructor is fishing for with the "no modulo" restriction.  I just verified it passes the stated test cases. +1

Comment: It is working great. I fully understand now how to make it, I learned a lot. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

*You can use the below implementation of **`addAndMultiply`** method to get the desired result as follows:*

**Logic:**

1. I have first initialised the `result` with the first element of the list and then save the `loopSize` as `size` of the `list`.
2. After that , I have checked whether the `loopSize` is **even or odd**, if even then modified the result by adding the last element of the list and reducing the `loopSize` by 1.
3. Now iterating the list from `i=1` to the `loopSize` with an increment of `i+2` and adding the `result` after multiplying the consecutive numbers as `(list.get(i) * list.get(i + 1))`.

**Code:**

```
static int addAndMultiply(List<Integer> list) {
    int result = list.get(0);
    int loopSize = list.size();
    if ((loopSize & 1) !=1) {
        result = result + list.get(loopSize - 1);
        loopSize = loopSize - 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < loopSize; i = i + 2) {
        result = result + (list.get(i) * list.get(i + 1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Testcases:**

```
Input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Output: 27

Input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Output: 33

Input: 1,2
Output: 3
```

Comment: OP can't use the modulo operator; I think your approach is good, just need to replace that expression with something else (I guess bitwise-AND with 1, and compare with 1:  `if ((loopSize & 1) != 1)` means it was even)

Comment: @Gus Thanks for highlighting it , I have somehow missed that part of not using the modulo operator as OP mentioned in the problem statement as well. Now, updated the way of checking the `loopSize` as even or odd using bitwise-AND operator as suggested by you.

Comment: Thank you for solution and clarification. Learned a lot from it. :)

Comment: @direeX Glad, it helped ! Thank you for kind appreciation.